Best way to replace a failing hard drive
I have a four drives in a RAID 5 array. One of the drives (sdb) show a lots of errors and the array has high latency during access.
I currently have one new disk and another one is commanded.
As part of the replacement I also want to grow the RAID level from RAID 5 to RAID 6. I identify to mean to achieve this :
By first growing to RAID 6:
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdf1 
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices 5 --level 6 --backup-file /<path>/mdadm-backup
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdb1 # Set faulty but keep it for replacement until a spare drive is available
# After my second drive arrived
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdg1

By first replacing the faulty drive then growing to RAID 6:
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdf1 
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdb1 --with /dev/sdf1
# after second drive is arrived
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdg1
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices 5 --level 6 --backup-file /path/mdadm-backup

Is there a difference between the two solutions? Is one is safer than the other by imposing less operations on disks into the array?
[Edit] adding smart result:
Sdb ( almost faulty )
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   072   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       22562487
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   077   077   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       29352
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4963671931
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   026   026   000    Old_age   Always       -       65627
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       4793
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   072   000    Old_age   Always       -       137445703785
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       107
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   073   056   045    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 25/28)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       82
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       296
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   027   044   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (0 14 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       35384
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   001   001   000    Old_age   Offline      -       35384
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

sbc
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   118   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       194860592
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       24
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       654004767
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   026   026   000    Old_age   Always       -       65631
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   062   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   073   059   045    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 24/27)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       82
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       295
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   027   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (0 14 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

sdd
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   113   094   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       51447952
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       665278320
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   026   026   000    Old_age   Always       -       65630
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       124
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       173
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       188
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   073   055   045    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 25/27)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       82
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       296
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   027   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (0 14 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0


I'm back with good news. This was the solution I use.
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdb1 --with /dev/sdf1

This have take 28 longs days to complete because the failing disk was not able to read to higher than 1,5M/s but finally my array is back in good state. I will now grow it to raid 6. Think @Halfgaar for your support.

Congratulations with handling this successfully, still have a suggestion how to prevent such situation in the future. Monitoring of the RAID is mandatory else you would only (ab)use its redundancy by chance if you noticed disks are failing, like you did. But also you need to run periodic consistency checks (scrubbing). Debian has that by default. That way, it may kick out an unstable disk early which you'd catch with monitoring. Using this strategy I managed to avoid seeing totally failed drives in MD RAID at all — I've replaced them all on early signs, like <100 relocated sectors.

@NikitaKipriyanov to elaborate, I've set up my monitoring to watch for kernel errors saying 'ata exception'. Drives will start throwing errors way before any RAID will kick them out, so this allows me to catch them early on. Caveat: this is for SATA drives. SAS and NVME may have different errors.

Well, I meant you better run mdadm check on a regular basis, like every month or every other month, depending on the size and the performance of the component devices, the load on the array and so on.

Yes, there is a difference, but I'm not sure which is better.
When you replace a disk in a RAID5, you need all other disks to be read-error free to reconstruct the new disk. With modern drives, that's no easy challenge. The read error chance on huge modern drives is almost such that you're guaranteed to run into one. That's why RAID5 is not recommended anymore. You can find a lot of info about this on the internet.
By migrating to RAID6, you will also incur a write load on the old disks. This may even be advantageous: a drive can have 'current pending sectors' (see SMART). This means sectors it deemed damaged. It will reallocate them as soon as they receive a new write. If the sector is still not good enough to receive the write, the counter for 'reallocated sectors' will rise. The sector will then, transparently, reside elsewhere on the disk.
My first step would be to look at the SMART status of your drives, and look at the above two parameters.
But, I'm hesitant to recommend one way over the other if your drives indeed do have pending sectors. I think if they don't, I would first replace the disk in the RAID5, because that incurs a non-destructive operation on the other disks.
And have/make backups...

I've edit my post with the Smart status of the faulty drive. As you can see "current pending sectors" and "reallocated sectors" are quite high. For the other 3 disks, one is a fresh disk with no error, and the others are the same age as the faulty but with 0/16 and 24/0 respectively for "reallocated sectors/current pending sectors"

@Scandinave you're somewhat in a bind. I think what I would do in your case, is boot the system with a sysrescue USB and clone the whole /dev/md0 device to a new disk (with dd). Then dd it back onto a brand new md device with new disks. That way you can still use as much redundancy of your failing drives as possible. And, it's a repeatable operation.

The problem is I've not a disk of the capacity that can handle all the data of the raid. I've already backup the important data. So what you are telling me is both method will fall ?

@Scandinave 'will' is a strong word, but yes, both 'good' disks have problems.

Ok. Thinks. I thinks I will try to go for the raid 6 ways. I've try to backup all remaining non important stuff into a S3 cloud provider with rclone but with a ~500kb/s, this give me arround 3y to complete :(

@Scandinave Let us know the outcome. I'm curious.

After ready the mdadm man page, I've launch a replacement of the faulty disk.This way my faulty that somehow currently still work is primary used to make the new drive.But this is extremely slow. Like about 50 days to complete at the current speed.

@Scandinave that means you're probably running into reading errors. What does dmesg -T  say?

Lots of :
I/O error, dev sdb, sector 91136256 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2 exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0 rq_stat 0x40000001 failed command: READ DMA status: { DRDY SENSE ERR } error: { UNC }

In my understand, when encountering errors, mdadm will try to correct them by reading parity data to the others disks. Am I true ?

@Scandinave Do I understand you're still in RAID5 mode and you replaced the disk? In that case, it's already reconstructing data from parity. There is no redundancy and every sector on all disks needs to function properly.

Nop. I added the fresh disk into the array as spare and did mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdb1 --with /dev/sdf1. As per the mdadm documentation, the replaced drive is kept into the array until the replace is done. So as i understand it, i keep the redundancy during the operation.

That‘s why regular scrubbing is so important with large drives - it guarantees that no undetected read errors accumulate and refreshes weak sectors in time.
